# Unable to execute nested Unix commands in Spark scala

Tags: scala, amazon-s3

I'm trying to list the folder in aws s3 and get only the filename out of it. The nested unix commands is not getting executed in Spark-shell and throwing error. I know we have other ways to do it by importing org.apache.hadoop.fs._

The command that I'm trying are :

```
import sys.process._

var cmd_exec = "aws s3 ls s3://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/"

cmd_exec !!
```

If I execute it by nesting the cut command to the ls. It's throwing error.

```
import sys.process._

var cmd_exec = "aws s3 ls s3://<bucket-name>/<folder-name>/ | cut -d' ' -f9-"

cmd_exec !!
```

> Error message: Unknown options: |,cut,-d',',-f9-
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Nonzero exit value: 255

Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this is natural.

```
import scala.sys.process._
   val returnValue: Int = Process("cat mycsv.csv | grep -i Lazio")!
```

above code also wont work...

`|` is  redirect operator to execute another command. so instead of that....
 capture the output and execute one more time..

you can see this [article - A Scala shell script example](https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-shell-script-example-exec-syntax) as well.. where scala program can be executed as shell script... it might be useful.

TIY!